# How can I instantiate a generic type in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I've added a human-readable configuration file to my app using [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and am trying to add a wrapper around it to make type conversions easier.  Specifically, I want the returned value to "inherit" it's type from the provided default value.  Here's what I've got so far:

```java
protected <T> T getProperty(String key, T fallback) {
    String value = properties.getProperty(key);

    if (value == null) {
        return fallback;
    } else {
        return new T(value);
    }
}
```

[(Full example source.)](http://pastebin.com/CWpzFziJ)

The return value from `getProperty("foo", true)` would then be a boolean regardless of whether it was read from the properties file and similarly for strings, integers, doubles, &c.  Of course, the above snippet doesn't actually compile:

```
PropertiesExample.java:35: unexpected type
found   : type parameter T
required: class
                        return new T(value);
                                   ^
1 error
```

Am I doing this wrong, or am I simply trying to do something which can't be done?

**Edit:** Usage example:

```java
// I'm trying to simplify this...
protected void func1() {
    foobar = new Integer(properties.getProperty("foobar", "210"));
    foobaz = new Boolean(properties.getProperty("foobaz", "true"));
}

// ...into this...
protected void func2() {
    foobar = getProperty("foobar", 210);
    foobaz = getProperty("foobaz", true);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you can't instantiate generic objects. Normally you could keep a reference to the `Class` object representing that type and use it to call [`newInstance()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29). However, this only works for the default constructor. Since you want to use a constructor with parameters, you'll need to look up the [`Constructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html) object and use it for the instantiation:

```
protected <T> T getProperty(String key, T fallback, Class<T> clazz) {
    String value = properties.getProperty(key);

    if (value == null) {
        return fallback;
    } else {

        //try getting Constructor
        Constructor<T> constructor;
        try {
            constructor = clazz.getConstructor(new Class<?>[] { String.class });
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
            //handle constructor not being found
        }

        //try instantiating and returning
        try {
            return constructor.newInstance(value);
        }
        catch (InstantiationException ie) {
            //handle InstantiationException
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
            //handle IllegalAccessException
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException ite) {
            //handle InvocationTargetException
        }
    }
}
```

However, seeing how much trouble it is to achieve this, including the performance cost of using reflection, it's worth looking into other approaches first.

If you absolutely need to take this route, and if `T` is limited to a distinct set of types known at compile time, a compromise would be to keep a static `Map` of `Constructor`s, which is loaded at startup - that way you don't have to dynamically look them up at every call to this method. For example a `Map<String, Constructor<?>>` or `Map<Class<?>, Constructor<?>>`, which is populated using a [static block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Comment: Even with a default constructor, it is better to use a `Constructor` object than to use `Class.newInstance()`. The error handling is different; using the `Class` method, some exceptions are reported with a misleading type. The `Constructor` method is consistent with other dynamic invocations.

Comment: @Kublai Khan — Works!  Even better, I was able to get `klazz` as `Class<T> klazz = (Class<T>)fallback.getClass();` to eliminate the extra parameter.  Thanks so much for your help!  **Edit:** I was starting to wonder about caching as soon as reflection entered the picture; I'll look at static blocks for that.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Just keep in mind that all dynamic lookups using reflection are quite expensive as they cannot be optimized at compile time.

Comment: @Kublai Khan — At this point, I'm thinking I may use this generic version during development, but switch to explicitly-typed methods before release.  By examining the cache, I'll be able to tell what types I've ended up needing to support.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that you cannot do.

Because of type erasure, the type `T`, while known at compile time, is not available to the JVM at run time.

For your specific problem, I think the most reasonable solution is to manually write the code for each different type:

```
protected String getProperty(String key, String fallback) { ... return new String(value); }
protected Double getProperty(String key, Double fallback) { ... return new Double(value); }
protected Boolean getProperty(String key, Boolean fallback) { ... return new Boolean(value); }
protected Integer getProperty(String key, Integer fallback) { ... return new Integer(value); }
```

Notes:

- In the Java standard API, you will find many places where there is a set of related methods that only differ by the input types.
- In C++, your probably could probably be solved by *templates*. But C++ introduces many other problems...

Comment: The respective parsing methods (e.g. `Integer#valueOf`) should be used instead of creating new instances. Starting with Java 9 the constructors are even marked as deprecated: [`Integer(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 1):

Generics are implemented using type erasure in Java. In English terms, most generic information are lost at compile time, and you can't know the actual value of `T` at runtime. This means you simply can't instanciate generic types.

An alternate solution is to provide your class with the type at runtime:

```
class Test<T> {

    Class<T> klass;

    Test(Class<T> klass) {
        this.klass = klass;
    }

    public void test() {
        klass.newInstance(); // With proper error handling
    }

}
```

Edit: New example closer to your case

```
static <T> T getProperty(String key, T fallback, Class<T> klass) {
    // ...

    if (value == null) {
        return fallback;
    }
    return (T) klass.newInstance(); // With proper error handling
}
```

Comment: I need to have a single instance of my class (`PropertiesExample`, here) be able to read properties of various types from the same file.  I'll add a usage example to my question.  :-)

Comment: First bit of code doesn't compile. T on the constructor is masking generic argument, and is in the wrong position. Additionally, exception checking is needed for newInstance().

Comment: Typo, fixed now. Exception checking was ommited for readability, hence the "With proper error handling" comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your existing method signature do it this way.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main
{
    private final Properties properties;

    public Main()
    {
        this.properties  = new Properties();
        this.properties.setProperty("int", "1");
        this.properties.setProperty("double", "1.1");
    }

    public <T> T getProperty(final String key, final T fallback)
    {
        final String value = this.properties.getProperty(key);
        if (value == null)
        {
            return fallback;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return (T) fallback.getClass().getConstructor(new Class<?>[] { String.class } ).newInstance(value);
            }
            catch (final InstantiationException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            catch (final IllegalAccessException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            catch (final InvocationTargetException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            catch (final NoSuchMethodException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Main m = new Main();
        final Integer i = m.getProperty("int", new Integer("0"));
        final Double d = m.getProperty("double", new Double("0"));
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses [functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

You could change the method signature to use a provided "parser":

```
protected <T> T getProperty(String key, T fallback, Function<String, ? extends T> parser) {
    String value = properties.getProperty(key);

    if (value == null) {
        return fallback;
    } else {
        return parser.apply(value);
    }
}
```

Also, for efficiency you might want to replace `T fallback` with `Supplier<? extends T> fallbackSupplier` to prevent having to create fallback values when they are not needed:

```
protected <T> T getProperty(String key, Supplier<? extends T> fallbackSupplier, Function<String, ? extends T> parser) {
    String value = properties.getProperty(key);

    if (value == null) {
        return fallbackSupplier.get();
    } else {
        return parser.apply(value);
    }
}
```

Then you can use [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) and [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) as parser and fallback supplier, e.g.:

```
protected void func2() {
    foobar = getProperty("foobar", () -> 210, Integer::valueOf);
    // Better create own parsing method which properly handles 
    // invalid boolean strings instead of using Boolean#valueOf
    foobaz = getProperty("foobaz", () -> true, Boolean::valueOf);

    // Imagine creation of `ExpensiveObject` is time-wise or 
    // computational expensive
    bar = getProperty("bar", ExpensiveObject::new, ExpensiveObject::parse);
}
```

---

The advantage of this approach is that it is not restricted to a (potentially non-existent) constructor anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
protected <T> T getProperty(String key, T fallback) {
    String value = properties.getProperty(key);

    if (value == null) {
        return fallback;
    } else {
        Class FallbackType = fallback.getClass();
        return (T)FallbackType.cast(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is better, but you need to create a new instance via reflection, using the value as an argument. The downvote is not from me, by the way; I was going to suggest this approach myself, but I wasn't able to figure out a way to do it type safely. Try to get rid of the unsafe cast to `T`.