# Calling constructor of a generic type

Tags: java, generics

If I have an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class Item
{
    private Integer value;
    public Item()
    {
        value=new Integer(0);
    }
    public Item(Integer value)
    {
        this.value=new Integer();
    }
}
```

And some classes deriving from Item like this:

```
public class Pencil extends Item
{
    public Pencil()
    {
        super();
    }
    public Pencil(Integer value)
    {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

I have not understood why I can't call the constructor using a generic:

```
public class Box <T extends Item>
{
    T item;
    public Box()
    {
        item=new T(); // here I get the error
    }
}
```

I know that is possible to have a type which hasn't a constructor, but this case is impossible because Pencil has the constructor without parameters, and Item is abstract.
But I get this error from eclipse:
*cannot instanciate the type T*
I don't understand why, and how to avoid this?

Comment: Consider the case when you have another class that extends `Item`, except this class has only one constructor that insists on at least one argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I instantiate a generic type in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916346/how-can-i-instantiate-a-generic-type-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create instance of generic type in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

Comment: For all the peoples that need something like that i think the simplest solution is to make the below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to use the Java type system to enforce that a class hierarchy has a uniform signature for the constructors of its subclasses.

Consider:

```
public class ColorPencil extends Pencil
{
    private Color color;

    public ColorPencil(Color color)
    {
        super();
        this.color=color;
    }   
}
```

This makes ColorPencil a valid T (it extends Item). However, there is no no-arg constructor for this type.  Hence, T() is nonsensical.

To do what you want, you need to use reflection.  You can't benefit from compile-time error checking.

Answer (score 15):

This is because Java uses erasure to implement generics, see this:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure

To quote the relevant parts from the above Wikipedia article:

> Generics are checked at compile-time for type-correctness. The generic type information is then removed in a process called type erasure.
>
> As a result of type erasure, type parameters cannot be determined at run-time.
>
> Consequently, instantiating a Java class of a parameterized type is impossible because instantiation requires a call to a constructor, which is unavailable if the type is unknown.

You can go around this by actually providing the class yourself. This is well explained here:

- [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answer was exactly what I was looking for or let say: it matches perfectly to my misunderstanding of the Java's generic implementation. :-)

Comment: @MichaelDorner Sure thing, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can place an abstract method so that the implementing class can determine how to construct the new object.

```
public abstract T constructT();
```

and instead of calling

```
T t = new T()
```

you would call

```
T t = constructT();
```

On your implementing call it would be created as:

```
new Box<Integer>() {
    public Integer constructT(){ return new Integer(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because at runtime the type of T is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

`T` is an alias for the actual type your class will handle, for example if you instantiate `Box<Item>` then `T` is really just an alias for `Item`. As you declare `T extends Item` then you know that `T` will have at least the same interface as `Item`, so you can treat it like one.

I think what you really want to do is not instantiate the `item` field in `Box`, but instead implement a couple of methods to let you manipulate that field.

```
public class Box<T extends Item> {
    private T item;

    public T getItem() {
        return this.item;
    }

    public void setItem(T item) {
        return this.item = item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to use T to call a constructor because if it would be possible than after a compilation you would get the code like this:

```
public class Box{
    Object item;
    public Box(){
        item = new Object();
    }
}
```

So if you would use this code and pass some object than you expect that there is the constructor of some specific type is called, but instead you get the Object constructor.

Comment: Well, only impossible because of the specifics of how Java's generics are implemented

Answer (score 0):

You can actually require a constructor for a generic type. It's not perfect but have a look at this:

```
public interface Constructor<T> {
    T constructor() ;
}
```

It's a general purpose functional interface to describe every noArgs constructor. The `java.util.function.Supplier` can also be used as it is equivalent.

```
public class Box <T extends Item>
{
    T item;
    public Box(Constructor<T> ctor)
    {
        item= ctor.constructor();
    }
}
```

This would look somewhat like this on the callsite:

```
Box<Pencil> box = new Box<>(Pencil::new);
```