# Generic method defining with generic paramater and return value

Tags: java, generics, jakarta-ee, methods, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling constructor of a generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366121/calling-constructor-of-a-generic-type)

I want to write a method to check null for a value of anytype and return the value of the same type accordingly. How can i write it in a generic way so that i can pass any parameter and return the same if it is not null or a new object of the same type?

Something like this will be helpful, but obviously the below wont work:

```
public T getValue(T param) {
    if (null != param) {
        return param;
    } else {
        return ""; // or return new T
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked before many times.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916346/how-can-i-instantiate-a-generic-type-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187109/instance-of-type-generic

Comment: And in each case, the answer is "you can't really, unless you're both willing to pass around the `Class` object, and you're willing to accept the fragility of that approach."

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Can you please explain it a bit? What do you mean by pass around the class object?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to pass in a default value explicitly:

```
public <T> T valueOrDefault(T input, T fallback) {
    return input == null? fallback : input;
}
```

which can be used like:

```
String query = valueOrDefault(getParameter("query"), "");

if (query.length() == 0) {

    ...
}
```

The problem with Java generics (as opposed to, for example, C#) is, that there is no type information retained after compilation, which would allow something like `new T()` to work. As an alternative approach (as was proposed in the comments to your question), you might pass in the class token:

```
public <T> T valueOrDefault(Class<T> token, T value) {
    if (value != null) return value;
    else {
        final Constructor<T> ctor = token.getConstructor();
        return ctor.newInstance();
    }
}
```

(error checking omitted for brevity; code not tested, might not even compile...) This approach is pretty brittle, though.

1. What if `T` does not have a default constructor?
2. What if the default constructor does non-trivial stuff?
3. What if a value isn't really usable after construction with the default constructor (because additional initialisations are required)?